# Parse response from url in json

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

How can i parse this url which gives Json response ?

```
 $.getJSON('http://url.php?id=chat_init&sess_d='+sessionID+'&user_id='+document.getElementById("user_id").value+    '&to_id='+document.getElementById("to_id").value,function (data) {

         alert(data.status);
         alert(data.msg);
         alert(data.room_id);
```

Response:

```
{"status":1,"msg":"chat is initilize","room_id":13}


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var sessionID=null ; 
    function A() { 
        $.getJSON('url.php?id=login&email='+document.getElementById("txtemail").value+'&password='+document.getElementById("txtpassword").value, function (data) { 
            sessionID = data.session_id;
            alert(data.status);
            alert(data.msg);
            alert(data.user_id);
            alert(sessionID);
        });
    }

    function B() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'url.php', 
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { 
                id: 'chat_init',
                sess_d: sessionID,
                user_id: $("#user_id").val(), 
                to_id: $("#to_id").val() 
        },success: function(data) { 
            alert(data.status); 
            alert(data.msg);
            alert(data.room_id); 
        }
    });

    //]]>
    </script>


</head>
<body>
    Username :

    <form>
        <input type="text" id="txtemail" />
        <br /><br />

        Password : <input type="password" id="txtpassword" />
        <br />

        <input type="button" value="Login" onclick="A()" />
        <br />

        My id is : <input type="text" id="user_id" />
        <br /><br />

        To ID is : <input type="text" id="to_id" />
        <br /><br />

        <textarea rows="10" cols="25"></textarea>
        <br /> <br />

        <textarea rows="2" cols="18"></textarea>

        <input type="button" value="Initialize chat" onclick="B()" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thankx for any help...

Comment: the JSON is already parsed for you. what do you mean by "parse this url"? *did you mean "parse the JSON"*? - i sound like Google.

Comment: yes i mean i am not getting the response that i have shown

Comment: i am working on dreamweaver. Any syntax error is shown there. So that is also ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="button" value="Initialize chat" id="B" /> <!--note the id-->

$(document).ready(function() {

    //using the button with id "B" to call beta
    $('#B').on('click', function() {
        beta();
    });

    function beta() {
        $.ajax({

            //base url
            url: 'url.php',  

            //parameters
            data: {         
                id: 'chat_init',
                sess_d: sessionID,
                user_id: $("#user_id").val(),
                to_id: $("#to_id").val()
            },

            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data.status);
                alert(data.msg);
                alert(data.room_id);
            }
        });
    }

});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g3zUe/

Answer (score 1):

That's kind of ugly, try rewriting it as a `$.ajax` call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'url.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { 
        id: 'chat_init', 
        sess_d: sessionID,
        user_id: $("#user_id").val(),
        to_id: $("#to_id").val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.status);
         alert(data.msg);
         alert(data.room_id);
    }
});
```

Comment: http://url.php?id=chat_init&sess_d=<session_id>&user_id=<from>&to_id=<chat_with>&title=<chat_title> This is my actual url.

Comment: No ,I am not getting response

Comment: have you tried manually inputting the url? have you checked the console? are you sure the server is returning JSON?

Comment: yes the server is returning json.  {"status":1,"msg":"chat is initilize","room_id":13} .This is the output when i am putting url. At console too there is no error

Comment: the `data` object in my example with the `$.ajax` call is what adds the query string attached to your URL in the example you gave. 

Is your remote PHP file in the same domain as this script? In your first example, you have "http://url.php". If the file you're calling is in a different domain from the script, then it's going to fail due to [same-origin policy enforcement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: I left it off accidentally. I've updated my answer to include the closing paren and semicolon.

Comment: You mentioned you were using the console. In the network tab, does it register the Ajax call is being made?

Comment: what did you mean by "register the Ajax call" ? In network there is nothing as such.

Comment: When the `ajax` method is called in your code, do you see the request appear in the network tab in the console? Which browser are you using?

Comment: In chrome, in the network tab, at the bottom of the window there are filter buttons. Click on the "XHR" button and it'll only show AJAX (XmlHttpRequest) requests. If its not showing up in there, then the Ajax method isn't being called by your script at all

Comment: Then `$.ajax()` is not being triggered at all. So you're not getting a response because you aren't making the request.

Comment: When or how do you trigger the `$.ajax` method? Are you sure the parent method is getting triggered?

Comment: i ediited my ques. could you take a look?

Comment: What actually calls `A()` or `B()`? Based on the example you gave, it doesn't look like anything actually triggers those functions. What happens if you just type `A();` or `B();` in the console and press enter?

Comment: Username :  <input type="text" id="txtemail" /><br/><br/>Password :  <input type="password" id="txtpassword"/><br/> <input type="button" value="Login" onClick="A()" /><br />My id is :  <input type="text" id="user_id" /> <br /><br />To ID is :  <input type="text" id="to_id"   /><br /><br /><textarea rows="10" cols="25"> </textarea><br /><br /><textarea rows="2" cols="18"> </textarea><input type="button"value="Initialize chat"  onClick="B()"></body></html>   sorry  missed it.

Comment: Inside `A()` and `B()` and before the `$.getJSON` and `$.ajax` calls, add in a `console.log('A() was called');` and `console.log('B() was called');` to verify that each of those functions is being triggered.

Comment: yes they are triggered. Shows "A() was called
chat.html:28B() was called"

Comment: Do you have the jQuery library loaded/included in your page?

Comment: I added a new answer above, take a look and let me know the results.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your HTML and jQuery code. I tested it on my end it and it does [indeed make the AJAX call](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2540784/CloudShot/shot_2232012_103759_am.png), but since I don't have `url.php` on my server, it gets a 404 error. See how this works for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var sessionID = null; 
    function A() { 
        $.getJSON('url.php', {
            id: 'login',
            email: $("#txtemail").val(),
            password: $("#txtpassword").val() 
        }, function (data) { 
            sessionID = data.session_id;
            alert(data.status);
            alert(data.msg);
            alert(data.user_id);
            alert(sessionID);
        });
    }

    function B() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'url.php', 
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { 
                id: 'chat_init',
                sess_d: sessionID,
                user_id: $("#user_id").val(), 
                to_id: $("#to_id").val() 
            },
            success: function(data) { 
                alert(data.status); 
                alert(data.msg);
                alert(data.room_id); 
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#loginButton").click(A);
        $("#initChatButton").click(B);
    });

    //]]>
    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <p>Username : <input type="text" id="txtemail" /></p>
        <p>Password : <input type="password" id="txtpassword" /></p>
        <p><input type="button" value="Login" id="loginButton" /></p>

        <p>&nbsp;</p>

        <p>My id is : <input type="text" id="user_id" /></p>

        <p>To ID is : <input type="text" id="to_id" /></p>
        <p><textarea rows="10" cols="25"></textarea></p>

        <p><textarea rows="2" cols="18"></textarea></p>

        <p><input type="button" value="Initialize chat" id="initChatButton" /></p>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```